# How do I add elements (integers or string) in the middle of my doubly-linked list? -Java

Tags: java, linked-list, doubly-linked-list

1. This code allows me to create a linked list and I want to be able to add elements
   between two nodes.
2. I'm having trouble understanding how to set it up so I can insert a number between 40 and 30.

---

```java
public class DoublyLinkedList<E> {

    private static class Node<E> {
        //Node Fields
        private E element;
        private Node<E> prev;
        private Node<E> next;

        // Node Constructor
        public Node(E e, Node<E> p, Node<E> n) {
            this.element = e;
            this.prev = p;
            this.next = n;
        }

        // Node Methods
        public E getElement() {
            return element;
        }

        public Node<E> getPrev() {
            return this.prev;
        }

        public Node<E> getNext() {
            return this.next;
        }

        public void setPrev(Node<E> p) {
            this.prev = p;
        }

        public void setNext(Node<E> n) {
            this.next = n;
        }

    }

    // DLinkedList Fields
    private Node<E> header;
    private Node<E> trailer;
    int size;

    // DLinkedList Constructor
    public DoublyLinkedList() {
        this.header = new Node<>(null, null, null);
        this.trailer = new Node<>(null, this.header, null);
        this.header.setNext(this.trailer);
    }

    // DLinkedList Methods
    public int size() {
        return this.size;
    }

    public E first() {
        if (isEmpty()) {
            return null;
        }
        return this.header.next.getElement();
    }

    public E last() {
        if (isEmpty()) {
            return null;
        }
        return this.trailer.prev.getElement();
    }

    public boolean isEmpty() {
        return size == 0;
    }

    public void addFirst(E e) {
        addBetween(e, this.header, this.header.getNext());
    }

    public void addLast(E e) {
        addBetween(e, this.trailer.getPrev(), this.trailer);
    }

    public void addBetween(E e, Node<E> predecessor, Node<E> successor) {
        Node<E> newest = new Node<>(e, predecessor, successor);
        predecessor.setNext(newest);
        successor.setPrev(newest);
        this.size++;
    }

    public E removeFirst() {
        if (this.isEmpty()) {
            return null;
        }
        return this.remove(header.getNext());
    }

    public E removeLast() {
        if (this.isEmpty()) {
            return null;
        }
        return this.remove(trailer.getPrev());
    }

    public E remove(Node<E> e) {
        e.next.setPrev(e.prev);
        e.prev.setNext(e.next);
        this.size--;
        return e.getElement();
    }

    public String toString() {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("(");
        Node<E> walk = this.header.next;
        while (walk != this.trailer) {
            sb.append(walk.element);
            if (walk.next != this.trailer)
                sb.append("--> ");
            walk = walk.next;
        }
        sb.append(")");
        return sb.toString();
    }
    // Node myList = new Node<E>(null, trailer, header);
    // myList.e.addFirst

    // Node myList2 = new Node<E>(null, 1, null);
}


class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // create a DoublyLinkedList object
        DoublyLinkedList Node = new DoublyLinkedList();
        // Add nodes to the list
        Node.addFirst(10);
        Node.addFirst(20);
        Node.addFirst(30);
        Node.addFirst(40);
        Node.addFirst(50);
        Node.removeFirst();
        Node.removeLast();
        //Node.addBetween(Node, null, null);

        // print the nodes of DoublyLinkedList
        System.out.println(Node);
    }
}
```

Comment: It looks like you already have a method called `addBetween`, but you haven't set it up so you have access to the `Node` objects for 30 and 40.  The easiest solution is probably just to have your `add` methods return the newly created `Node` objects.

Comment: So I'd be doing somehing like ` public void addFirst(E e) {
 addBetween(e, this.header, this.header.getNext());
 return Node = new DoublyLinkedList<>();
}`  ? Maybe I'm not understanding how to make each entry a node

Comment: What you should also think about: *comparing* Nodes. You see, in order to say: I want to add after Node(10) ... well, you need to be able to distinguish those Node objects. Meaning: you need to know what is INSIDE a node, and whether two node are equal nor not.

Comment: Unrelated: read about java naming conventions. Variable names start lower case. And then, remember: these names are for HUMAN readers. Use names that say what they mean, mean what they say. "Node" is very bad name. Because ... it isnt a single Node. It is an instance of your list. So why not just call it `numbers` for example?!

Answer (score 0):

Start by changing `addBetween` to return the node.

```java
    public Node<E> addBetween(E e, Node<E> predecessor, Node<E> successor) {
        Node<E> newest = new Node<>(e, predecessor, successor);
        predecessor.setNext(newest);
        successor.setPrev(newest);
        this.size++;
        return newest;
    }
```

Change `addFirst` and `addLast` to return that node.  I'll only show `addFirst`:

```
    public Node<E> addFirst(E e) {
        return addBetween(e, this.header, this.header.getNext());
    }
```

Save the nodes for 30 and 40:

```
Node<Integer> node30 = Node.addFirst(30);
Node<Integer> node40 = Node.addFirst(40);
```

Then you can use `addBetween`:

```
Node.addBetween(newNumber, node30, node40);
```

Comment: This doesn't quite work because I'm getting "Integers cannot be resolved to a type" now

Comment: Sounds like you typed `Integers` where I said `Integer`.  Are you sure you did this correctly?

Comment: For addLast, I did `public Node<E> addLast(E e) {
  return addBetween(e, this.trailer.getPrev(), this.trailer);
 }`                                                                                                                                            As for saving the nodes, I tried `Node<> node30 = node.addFirst(30);`

Comment: Type exactly what I wrote instead.  Not `Node<> node30`, but `Node<Integer>`, and you have to capitalize `Node` in `Node.addFirst` (since you defined your `Node` object with a capital `N`).

Comment: Capitol `N` doesn't seem to work for me...                                                                                     `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problems: 
        Node cannot be resolved to a type
        Node cannot be resolved

        at Main.main(DoublyLinkedList.java:140)`                                                                                 `Line 140: Node<Integer> node30 = Node.addFirst(30);`

Answer (score 0):

- You need not expose the class Node and indeed you made it private.
  But then you cannot navigate by Node, just by E. So `remove(Node)` is not possible as public method.
- Node's methods could be private too.
- Node need not be parametrized by `<E>`. That can even give serious programming problems, as there then are two `E`s. Remove it.
- `addBetween` is nicely symmetric, but `successor` is redundant. I would remove it as parameter and make it a local variable.
- Rename the local variable `Node` to `list`.

So:

```
private E removeNode(Node node) {
    node.next.setPrev(node.prev);
    node.prev.setNext(node.next);
    size--;
    return node.getElement();
}

private Optional<Node> find(E element) {
    for (Node node = header.next; node != trailer; node = node.next) {
        if (node.element == element) {
            return Optional.of(node);
        }
    }
    return Optional.empty();
}

public boolean remove(E e) {
    Optional<Node> nodeOpt = find(e);
    nodeOpt.ifPresent(n -> removeNode(n));
    return nodeOpt.isPresent();
}
```

The same for an `insertBefore(E)`, `insertAfter(E)`.